# Layout not showing from top in android

Tags: android

I am using the following xml Layout when i call this layout, Layout not showing from top of the Screen it is starting from the ListView and textview gets hide on top. we can see textview after scroll. Any suggestion???

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/homebg"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/mainlinearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ScrollView android:focusable="false" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:foregroundGravity="top">

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:focusable="true">

                <TextView android:layout_marginLeft="30dip" android:text="Americas"
                    android:textSize="22sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:id="@+id/tv_america" android:focusable="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
                </TextView>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:focusable="false">
                    <ListView android:background="@drawable/metro_selection_white_bg"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:id="@+id/americaslist1"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:focusable="false" android:layout_height="1150dp">
                    </ListView>

                    <TextView android:layout_gravity="top|left"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dip" android:text="Europe"
                        android:textSize="22sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dip" android:id="@+id/tv_europe">
                    </TextView>

                    <ListView android:background="@drawable/metro_selection_white_bg"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dip" android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
                        android:id="@+id/europelist2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dip" android:layout_height="490dp">
                    </ListView>

                    <TextView android:layout_gravity="top|left"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dip" android:text="Asia-Pacific"
                        android:textSize="22sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dip" android:id="@+id/tv_europe">
                    </TextView>

                    <ListView android:background="@drawable/rrbg2"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dip" android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
                        android:id="@+id/asiapacific" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dip" android:layout_height="240dp">
                    </ListView>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>![enter image description here][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the header and footer for a listview...

```
public void addHeaderView(View v)
public void addFooterView(View v)
```

Add your textview using the above API's it should be shown above and below the listview..

Comment: Thanks for Ur reply. i know about header and footer view but i have to design according to attached screen shots...

Comment: add a background resource for the text view which is the same the background image and add it as a header and don't add any footer..